# Did William Ward write "An Address At a Meeting of the Society for Political Information held at the Talbot Inn in Derby, July 16th 1792"?

Tags: political-history, sources

[William Ward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Ward_(missionary)) (1769–1823) the Baptist missionary assistant to William Carey (1761-1834) was a Derby man and, as a youth at any rate, a radical. He is said to have been the author of "[An Address At a Meeting of the Society for Political Information held at the Talbot Inn in Derby, July 16th 1792](https://www.wmcarey.edu/carey/wmward/Digi%20html/dspi1.html)"  which was picked up and reprinted by a London journal, the Morning Chronicle.

The journal's owners were subsequently prosecuted for sedition at the King's Bench (09/12/1793) but an acquittal was secured by lawyer Thomas Erskine (1750-1823) who later went on to become famous for his defense of radicals and whose work led to the Criminal Lunatics Act (1800) and the Treason Act (1800).

After the trial Erskine said he was under the impression the Address was by Erasmus Darwin (1731-1802) who was then living in Derby.

The authority for all this is [John Clerk Marshman's "Life and Times of Carey, Marshman and Ward" (1859) Volume 1 p.94.](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.80466/page/n125/mode/2up)

What I cannot find is any concrete evidence that the address was by Ward.

It is signed by the chairman "S Eyre", but obviously no one thought he wrote it himself. Is Marshman the only authority for this?

Comment: Strange: Who is Eyre, why is it Ward given all the credit on this, as Darwin and him were _both_ in the club, so presumably a collaboration equally likely? Drewry and Ward are responsible, being owner and editor of the paper. Seems to me that Marshman's picture is indeed a bit flimsy? // There are some old theses to look after:  J. D. Andrew: 'The Derby Newspaper Press 1720–1855' Reading,  1955 and E Fearne, both not online AFAIK. Same offline glory to perhaps Jenny Graham’s 'The Nation, The Law and The King'?

Comment: Not sure that Darwin was in the Soc. for Political information. I have no evidence that Darwin and Ward moved in the same circles. Ward was a non-conformist. Darwin did have non conformist friends but they were all unitarians or leaning towards unitarianism. Ward would have been in the opposite camp I'm pretty sure.  I can't find anything on Eyre. It was Perry, of the London Morning Chronicle that got prosecuted for reprinting the Address not the Derby paper.

Comment: Conflicting info on the web: ["Darwin… founded the Derby Society for Political Information"](https://victorianweb.org/science/edarwin/politics1.html); wasn't the address first published in Derby under Drewry/Ward? IDK, but [" J. D. Andrew in 'The Derby Newspaper Press 1720-1855' says: 'Ward drew up an address letter published by Derry in 'The Morning Chronicle', which became the subject of a prosecution."](https://www.wmcarey.edu/carey/wmward/Main%20html/derby01.html) Note that "Derry" seems to be [sic!] and a misprint of unknown significance.

Comment: Darwin founded the Derby Philosophical Society (Desmond King-Hele "Doctor of Revolution" p.153) Not the Society for Political Information. Yes the Address was first published in Derby by Drewry/Ward. You can find reprints in various places but the one that attracted prosecution was by Perry in the Morning Chronicle.https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Begin_At_a_meeting_of_the_Society_for_Po.html?id=wcJbAAAAcAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: Note that I endorse this endeavour, not criticise it, and merely point to minor additions of the Q or potential leads for As: Darwin may have been both? ["Erasmus Darwin was a founding member of one of the local societies inspired by Paine’s ideas, the Derby Society for Political Information (King-Hele 1999, p. 276)."](https://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/letter/DCP-LETT-12368.xml)

Comment: I think I am going to tackle this by closely comparing the style and language of the Address with Erasmus Darwin's other writings and the writings (if I can find them) of Ward.